# POO Menu de comidas/ precios

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, poo, estructuras-de-datos

Les comparto este ejercicio que estoy haciendo; es inicial sobre POO. No entiendo bien como funciona el def str... el ejercicio es así:

Estás digitalizando la información de tu restaurante. Para manejar la información del menú decides crear la clase `Menu`. La clase deberá recibir los parámetros: `comidas` (lista de strings) y `precios` (lista de ints del mismo largo que la lista comidas). Además, deberás definir el método str(self).

Este método deberá retornar tantas líneas como comidas tenga el menú, donde cada línea deberá ser una comida seguida de dos puntos y su precio.

```
Pato a la mostaza: 20000 
Hamburguesa: 8000 
Ensalada: 6000 
Lasagna: 9000
```

Tu código deberá ejecutarse correctamente con un código como el siguiente:

```py
comidas = ['Pato a la mostaza', 'Hamburguesa', 'Ensalada', 'Lasagna'] 
precios = [20000, 8000, 6000, 9000] 
menu = Menu(comidas, precios)

print(menu)
```

Esto es lo que estoy intentando hacer ... pero estoy en problemas ...

```
class Menu: 
    def init(self, comidas,precios) -> None: 
        self.comidas=comidas 
        self.precios=precios 
    
    def str(self) -> str: 
        for i in comidas: 
            for j in precios: 
                return ( i , (':'), j ) 
            break
        
        
        
comidas = ['Pato a la mostaza', 'Hamburguesa', 'Ensalada', 'Lasagna'] 
precios = [20000, 8000, 6000, 9000] 
menu = Menu(comidas, precios)

print(menu)
```

Comment: Edite la pregunta para que fuera un poco mas claro el codigo pero no estoy seguro si el `break` deberia de ir en esa parte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estás lejos de conseguir el objetivo, pero hay varios detalles importantes, para comenzar:

1. El *constructor* de la clase tiene el nombre `__init__`, y no puedes cambiarlo, pues son llamados automáticamente mediante su nombre desde las partes internas del programa.
2. Ya que las especificaciones del problema dicen que los arreglos pasados al constructor son de la misma longitud, haría falta verificar esto antes de *aceptarlos*, pues nada garantiza que el programador final cumpla con este requerimiento y, como se verá más adelante, en cambio el buen funcionamiento de la clase si depende de él. Para esto, me valdré de una *aserción*, que es un tipo de programación diseñada para prevenir este tipo de errores:

Así, el método quedaría:

```
    def __init__(self, comidas: list, precios: list) -> None: 
        assert len(comidas) == len(precios), "comidas debe tener la misma longitud que precios para crear el Menú"
        self.comidas=comidas 
        self.precios=precios
```

Luego:

1. El método para obtener una representación textual de un objeto debe llamarse `__str__` y tampoco podemos cambiar su nombre.
2. En este método, estás cometiendo el error de iterar de manera anidada por ambas listas. Esto te va a dar el producto cartesiano de las mismas, combinando cada comida con cada precio. No es eso lo que queremos, sino queremos iterar por ambas listas *a la vez*, para ir obteniendo cada comida y cada precio, en el mismo orden.
   Esto podemos lograrlo con un único ciclo. Podríamos ir por el índice de las listas, por ejemplo, podríamos obtener la cadena que representa cada línea el el menú con un ciclo como el que sigue:

   ```
   for i in range(len(comidas)):
       x = comidas[i] + ": " + str(precios[i])
   ```

   Aquí se hace importante que ambas listas tengan la misma longitud, de otra manera el código podría fallar con un error (si la lista de comidas tiene más elementos que la de precios).

   Sin embargo, considero más *pythonista* el uso de `zip()`, que recibe varias listas y nos devuelve una lista de tuplas con cada uno de los elementos de la lista.

   Así, podemos obtener el mismo resultado con:

   ```
   for (comida, precio) in zip(comidas, precios):
       x = comida + ": " + str(precio)
   ```
3. La sentencia `return` hace que termine la ejecución del método, por lo que usualmente se llama una única vez. Si ves código dónde aparece varias veces o aparece condicionalmente dentro de un ciclo, es porque es intención del programador que la ejecución del método termine cuando se alcance la primera de ellas. No tiene sentido colocarla dentro de un ciclo sin condiciones, pues realmente no habrá *ciclo* alguno, ya que se ejecutará el código una única vez hasta encontrar la sentencia `return` y terminará, no solo el ciclo, sino el método completo, por lo que tampoco se ejecutará nada que esté después del ciclo.

   Dado que tu lo que quieres es retornar varias líneas, tienes que encontrar una solución dónde esas líneas se produzcan todas y al final llamar una única vez a return. De otra forma vas a obtener solo la primera línea y nunca las siguientes.

   Para lograr esto, lo que sugiero que hagas es ir poniendo estas cadenas que formarán la salida en una nueva lista y finalmente usar `"\n".join(lista)` para convertirlas en una salida de múltiples líneas

Aplicando esto, el método quedaría así:

```
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        tex = []
        for (comida, precio) in zip(comidas, precios):
            tex.append(comida + ": " + str(precio))
        return "\n".join(tex)
```

Con estos cambios, el siguiente código:

```
comidas = ['Pato a la mostaza', 'Hamburguesa', 'Ensalada', 'Lasagna'] 
precios = [20000, 8000, 6000, 9000] 
menu = Menu(comidas, precios)
print(menu)
```

Produce la salida:

```
Pato a la mostaza: 20000
Hamburguesa: 8000
Ensalada: 6000
Lasagna: 9000
```

Comment: hola maestro, como siempre, excelente respuesta, solo quería recordarte, que no es buena idea hacer correcciones de identación en las preguntas de python, ya que pueden enmascarar errores, se que estás perfectamente capacitado para discernir cuando es prudente hacerlo, pero me parece que aprobar ediciones de usuarios nuevos... está un poco flojito.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, ciertamente no me dí cuenta que el editor anterior había realizado cambios en la indentación, si no, ni lo toco. Seré más cuidadoso en el futuro, gracias por el jalón de orejas, si que era necesario.

Comment: Maestro, el agradecido soy yo, por todo lo que aportas, y no, no es un jalón de orejas, es solo un recordatorio.

Comment: Hola. Desde ya muchas gracias por la docencia.  Tengo mucho para pensar.

Comment: Si pueden aportarme  de donde leer . Muchas Gracias. Soy nuevo en programación . Muy nuevo. Vengo del Area de salud con titulo de grado Y posgrado ... pero en esto  estoy desarmado. Pero me gusta.

Comment: @Ivan, es genial, bienvenido a la programación, espero que aprendas y estoy seguro que va a servirte mucho, a tí y a muchos que se beneficien de tu conocimiento. Hay mucho para leer. Si puedes leer en Inglés, mi recomendación es que lo hagas en ese idioma. Hay 10 veces más información y está más actualizada que en español. Como sea, si tienes disposición a invertir, puedes buscar libros de introducción a la programación, programación orientada a objetos, estructuras de datos y bases de datos, que son más o menos la base de todo. Pueden ser python pero los conceptos son más o menos universales.

Comment: Hola . Pensé que ya tenia esto resuelto pero ... termine el resto de ejercicios ... pero este me tira este error....RuntimeErrorElement(RuntimeError,Error on line 7:
    for (comida, precio) in zip(comidas, precios):
NameError: name 'comidas' is not defined
)

Comment: `self.comidas`, funciona?

Comment: Hola. Gracias por responder. Pense lo mismo    en   for (comida, precio) in zip(comidas, precios): aunque  tendría que poner self.comidas , self.precios tambien?...

Comment: sería `for (comida, precio) in zip(self.comidas, self.precios):`

Comment: Claro for (comida, precio) in zip(self.comidas, self.precios): ... y conceptualmente cual seria el error ? gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: hola.Gracias. Ese era el error. Gracias

Comment: @Ivan, veo que has hecho varias preguntas y has recibido algunas respuestas que seguramente han sido de ayuda. Te invito a votar a favor en ellas y aceptar las que te hayan ayudado a resolver tus inquietudes/dudas/problemas. Más información en [qué hacer si me responden](/help/someone-answers)